# Adding a help switch to a console application

Tags: c, linux, console-application

I would like to know how to make applications that are run in the terminal. What I mean by that is a program where they can type `-h` for help at any time and they have different choices of what commands to run... i.e. any linux application that you run out of terminal.

Any resources would be appreciated.

Comment: You might like to have look at `man 3 getopt`. The `getopt*()` family of functions provides a convenient way of implementing and parsing command line options like `-h`.

Answer (score 4):

in C, your main routine is usually written as:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

That `argv` array are the arguments (`argv[0]` is the name of the command you ran), so you could just check `if(argc > 1 && !strcmp(argv[1], "-h"))` to see if you are running as `-h` (and just use `printf` to print to the terminal).

If you want a more proper argument parsing library, look at `getopt` (https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Example-of-Getopt.html).  The GNU version (which is the one most Linux distros use) also has features for long arguments (handling `-h` and `--help`)

Comment: The `argp` functions are also in Glibc and could be easier to use, see [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Argp.html)

Answer (score 0):

[Nirk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17985022/63743) gave the best answer you can reasonably expect.  You are asking a pretty wide question here.  I would add that you should download the source of the [GNU Core Utils](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/) and wade through the code as best your can.  Most of those command line utility programs spend 75% of the code collecting, grouping, processing, checking, etc., command line arguments! Pick a  program with a few simple options because the complicated ones will blow the top of your head off for at least a few hours.